# RemoteFX Warning

Tags: windows-10, remotefx

Out of nowhere just received the following warning which states

> You are currently using the RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter. We no longer
> support this adapter and continued use may expose your machine to
> security risks. Learn more
> (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131976)

[image: RemoteFX Warning]

Going to the respective link I can see

> Disablement: RemoteFX vGPU will be disabled in all applicable Windows
> platforms in the July 2020 Windows security updates (July 14, 2020).

but nothing on disabling RemoteFX.

According to [Markus Lassfolk](https://www.isolation.se/remotefx-warning-how-to-disable-remotefx-in-windows-10/), we can open PowerShell as admin and run

```
Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter | Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
```

but this gets me

[image: Disable RemoteFX]

If I run

```
Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
```

as stated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/disable-vmremotefxphysicalvideoadapter?view=win10-ps) then I get prompt to enter a Name[0]. Simply clicking enter will get the following result

[image: Hm... not really working]

What should I do now?

Comment: Go to the link in the warning message and disable RemoteFX

Comment: @BoppityBop - Have you tried using `Remove-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter` instead?  What is the name of the VM?  Of course since you are not the author of this question, knowing information from you, isn't helpful to answer the author's question

Comment: I asked this separately: https://superuser.com/questions/1597409/warning-you-are-currently-using-the-remotefx-3d-video-adapter?noredirect=1#comment2434767_1597409 .. i dont have any VM currently.bottom line is - i want to make sure i am safe.

Comment: 3 months are now gone since the pop-up first appeared. From the moment I followed the steps mentioned in the question, the pop-up didn't show up anymore. So it might be that the answer is, "don't do anything else apart from what you already did".