# Warning "You are currently using the RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter"

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, security, graphics-card, hyper-v

I have received warning popup box "You are currently using the RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter. We no longer support this adapter ..." after I installed new graphic card.

I tried to open link provided in this message: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4570006/update-to-disable-and-remove-the-remotefx-vgpu-component

But it seems it describes a Windows update which supposed to disable this feature. Not how to disable it by hand.

Googling yielded two results - `Remove-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter` - which is not applicable in my case - I have Hyper-V running on my machine but I have no VMs. And this command works with VMs.

Another one - `Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter` - it requires name. So I ran get first:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
WARNING: We no longer support the RemoteFX 3D video adapter. If you are still using this adapter, you may become
vulnerable to security risks. Learn more (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131976)


Id                          : pci#ven_10de&dev_1d01&subsys_375d1458&rev_a1#4&2ae1b128&0&0019
Name                        : NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030
GPUID                       : 4318_7425_928846936_161
TotalVideoMemory            : 36392450048
AvailableVideoMemory        : 36392450048
DedicatedSystemMemory       : 0
DedicatedVideoMemory        : 2078662656
SharedSystemMemory          : 34313787392
Enabled                     : False
CompatibleForVirtualization : True
DirectXVersion              : 12.1
PixelShaderVersion          : 5.0
DriverProvider              : NVIDIA
DriverDate                  : 2019-07-24 02:00:00Z
DriverInstalledDate         : 2019-07-24 02:00:00Z
DriverVersion               : 26.21.14.3200
DriverModelVersion          : 2.6
CimSession                  : CimSession: .
ComputerName                : xxxxx
IsDeleted                   : False
```

then:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter -Name "NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030"
WARNING: We no longer support the RemoteFX 3D video adapter. If you are still using this adapter, you may become
vulnerable to security risks. Learn more (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131976)
```

My OS is W10 v 2004 build 19041.572 and Windows Update shows that everything is up to date..

**How do I make sure this "RemoteFX 3D" is securely disabled?**

Comment: Getting the same popup...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also kept receiving that popup. I do not have any VM running but I do have WSL2 running, which it does on top of Hyper-V (plus Docker using WSL2, I do not know if this plays a role in it).

Here is what I did :

1. Get the name of the video card. Here I could see that the driver was enabled.

```
Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
```

[image]

2. Disable RemoteFX adapter. Obviously, provide it with the name of your own card.

```
Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter -Name "NVIDIA Geforce GTX 970"
```

Now I cannot really check if this worked because the popup only appears very not-often, but it does show disabled :

[image]

Comment: It's possibly better to disable with the -Id flag instead, since two adapters can have the same name, but not the same Id?

Comment: What exactly will it disable? I feel like disabling a display output might be a bad Idea, if I don't understand what will turn dark afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: @zylstra There is no `-Id` flag

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy It will disable the ability for VMs to use your GPU, through the vGPU with RemoteFX. You can check this KB for alernatives : https://support.microsoft.com/help/4570006

Comment: @MickaelV.I could have sworn -Id is what I used.  Whatever the case then, I see that I cannot use it now.  And the great thing about -Name is that it (now) disables ALL adapters with that name, so you only have to enter the command once.

Answer (score 14):

After reading @Mickael's answer, this worked for me (at an Admin Powershell prompt):

```
Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter | ?{$_.Enabled} | Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
```

Comment: Nice all-in-one solution. Thanks! :) --- Makes you wonder why, if this is suitable, MS don't just push this as part of the update that provided the annoying pop-up!

Answer (score 1):

I just had my first experience with this: the Microsoft link has a tidbit - it seems MS will eventually remove the adapter from Windows in March 2021, and it seems disabling is the best we can do for now. But I am still looking for a manual deletion method.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-disable-and-remove-the-remotefx-vgpu-component-in-windows-bbdf1531-7188-2bf4-0de6-641de79f09d2

> Removal: RemoteFX vGPU will be removed from all applicable Windows
> platforms in the March 2021 Windows security updates (March 9, 2021)

In the mean time, I found this one liner in PS appears to disable the feature:

```
Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter | Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
```